# Extract Specific Fields With Keywords

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match the following string for an interface to a security system:

```
*3824 04:57:04 24/02/16 ALARM(DC4) Input 1 (SI)Main Door Opened(DC2)
```

Please note that `(DC4)` / `(SI)` / `(DC2)` are just the Visual representation of the ASCII characters so the input on the serial port would be a single byte, not 4/5 bytes.

The system will be continuously sending messages in a similar format to the above and I will need to check each one and see if it requires further processing.

The word ALARM is my keyword so if a message without ALARM in it comes though then I will be ignoring it (MATCH Failed).

If the word ALARM appears in the message then I need to get the location of the event and pass onto other layers within my application.

Sample 1 *3824 04:57:04 24/02/16 ALARM(DC4) Input 1 (SI)Main Door Opened(DC2)

Sample 2 *3824 04:57:04 24/02/16 ALARM(DC4) Input 2 (SI)Back Door Opened(DC2)

So I need to extract everything between the (SI) and (DC2) ASCII characters as a string for further processing.

So Message 1 would match "Main Door Opened" and Message 2 would match "Back Door Opened".

The other layers in the application will then extract this string from the appropriate Group # field if the match is a success.

Thanks,

Daniel.

Comment: Is the word `ALARM` always present ? What should be format of output string ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
([A-Z]+)(?:[^\)]+.){2}([^\(]+)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oI1eS7/2):

Input:

`*3824 04:57:04 24/02/16 ALARM(DC4) Input 1 (SI)Main Door Opened(DC2)`

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [24-29] `ALARM`
2.  [47-63] `Main Door Opened`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an exact match in group 1:

```
ALARM\(DC4\).*\(SI\)(.*)(?=\(DC2\))
```